# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume Kubernetes Error - Read only file system

Tags: kubernetes

I have on premise Kubernetes cluster which was running fine till yesterday but suddenly I have started getting below error and my containers are either in `ContainerCreating` or `Terminating` stage forever.

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-nc5kd" : mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b82bb668-d89e-43eb-9da4-ae5952a93ef1: read-only file system
```

Kubernetes version details

Client Version:

```
version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.2", GitCommit:"7f6f68fdabc4df88cfea2dcf9a19b2b830f1e647", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-17T14:20:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1
```

Server Version:

```
version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.2", GitCommit:"7f6f68fdabc4df88cfea2dcf9a19b2b830f1e647", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-05-17T14:13:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Events log for one of pod

```
Type     Reason       Age                From               Message
  ----     ------       ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    23s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/declarationapi-75c47847-kz5f9 to node-2
  Warning  Failed       12s (x2 over 24s)  kubelet            error making pod data directories: mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b82bb668-d89e-43eb-9da4-ae5952a93ef1: read-only file system
  Warning  FailedMount  8s (x6 over 23s)   kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-api-access-nc5kd" : mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b82bb668-d89e-43eb-9da4-ae5952a93ef1: read-only file system
```

And deployment yaml is

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: declarationapi
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: declarationapi
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: declarationapi
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: declarationapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: declarationapi
        image: <azure acr>/declarationapi
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"
            value: "Development"
          - name: "TZ"
            value: "Asia/Kolkata"
          - name: "RedisUri"
            value: "<redis connection>"
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: <acr-secrets>
...
```

**Update 1:**

With further investigations, I found that its with particular node only. Its working fine with one node but whenever cluster is trying to create pod on another node, above error occurs.

Comment: Based on your **Update 1**:

Check the package **nfs-common** is not available on the node which is required to mount the Persistent Volume shared using NFS.

**Install the package nfs-common** on the node on which the affected pod is running. Once the package is installed the pod will be able to mount the volume on the next retry. Refer to [Platform9](https://platform9.com/kb/kubernetes/pod-stuck-in-pending-state-as-container-fails-to-mount-persiste) doc for more information.

Comment: As per **[Assigning Pods to Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)**; You can constrain a Pod so that it is *restricted* to run on a particular node(s), or to *prefer* to run on particular nodes. You can use any of the following methods (as per doc) to choose where Kubernetes schedules specific Pods. Also refer to [how to assign a Kubernetes Pod to a particular node in a Kubernetes cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/#before-you-begin) for details.

Comment: Also check the **access mode set for the PVC in the PV definition file that matches the access mode required by the pod**. For example, if the pod requires read-write access, but the PVC is set to read-only, the pod will fail to mount the PVC.

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the above comments help to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: I am already making pods to run on particular node. I will try installing nfs-common on the other node.

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions and is your issue resolved?

Comment: There was some issue with VM and VM restoration fixed it. Thank you for your time